# Google Chrome cache buggery : Chrome does not fetch latest version of the page despite NO-CACHE

Tags: caching, google-chrome, no-cache

I want to know how to instruct Chrome not to use a cached version of a page. I cannot get Google Chrome [15.0.874.106 m] to load the latest version. There was a typo on the page and I've corrected it. Other browsers fetch the corrected page.  Chrome, not. Here below is what I have in the header section; should I add anything or change something?  Also, the browser is not set up "Under the Hood" to use any sort of DNS-prefetching.  Just to be clear, I don't want to clear the cache manually, but want to know how to manipulate Chrome's page-caching policies in a declarative manner.  Thanks

P.S. I had this problem once before (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798272/google-chrome-does-not-honor-cache-policy-in-page-header-if-the-page-is-displaye)) but the circumstances are somewhat different this time, so I don't know what's going on. This page too is being displayed in a frame, but it had a  no-cache policy from the get-go.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML LANG="en-US">

<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Wed, 26 May 2010 00:00:11 GMT">
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOARCHIVE">
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 .
 .
 .
</HEAD>
```

Comment: Does http://www.procata.com/cachetest/tests/nocache/ work for you? It passes for me in Chrome 17.0.924.0 canary. Are you behind some aggressive proxy or is all of this locally?

Comment: Procata tests succeed (assuming I've done them correctly; not absolutely certain I did).  I am loading a page from a remote server.