# Prevent google chrome cache html page

Tags: html, caching, google-chrome, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a page with another html page in iframe. In this iframe, i put this header tag

```
<META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

But chrome still cache it, when iframe content changed, hit f5 button but chrome still load cached version, not new version.

Please tell me how to pevent google chrome cache this iframe.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798272/google-chrome-does-not-honor-cache-policy-in-page-header-if-the-page-is-displaye

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the correct [expiry headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html) in the HTTP response from your server.  They override anything you've put in `meta` tags.

Comment: I'm noob at server managerment. I put this on .htaccess file :

<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>

Is good ?

Comment: @Tran Is it working?  You'll probably need to clear you browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Chrome:

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I found this in a Chromium bug.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28035

Comment: this  did not work for me, chrome still gets if from cache.

Comment: Just to let you know, this unfortunately does not work. Had these exact settings and a new release caused hell across the country!

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags can be ignored. Instead of them your server should set appropriate HTTP headers for cache control. You should also set the *Expired* header.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Avoiding_caching

Answer (score 0):

I found that Chrome may ignore those meta settings in the file in favor of the cache settings in http response header.  I was able to fix this issue in IIS by adding this in my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="NoControl" />
```

Files still get cached but now I can explicitly exclude a file if I need to.